# MediaWiki Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: mediawiki

I have installed MediaWiki on a test server, and have opened up port 80 on the Firewall.

I can access the site by typing in the following:

```
    http://NameOfServer/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

however there is only text displayed, no formatting of the site is correct.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of broken CSS.

- View the source code for the page.
- Try to open a few of the referenced CSS files with your browser -- some or all of them will fail.
- Determine why your browser cannot access the CSS files and fix that. Likely problems are file permissions or the redirect you set up for MediaWiki so that "index.php" doesn't have to be in the URL bar.